# Clock - How to change it?

Tags: ros, clock

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've been trying to work in simulation from massages that I have already recorded in a bag file, but I allways get warn messages saying that it is not possible to use the data because it is too old.

I've been reading about [simulating a clock](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Clock), but I can not figure it out how to use it. Could you help me please?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12311/clock---how-to-change-it?/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2011-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
What I normally do is I set the use_sim_time parameter to true:

$ rosparam set use_sim_time true

and then play the bag as following:

$ rosbag play bag.bag --clock

That shall get over the old messages hump.

D.

---

Originally posted by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) with karma: 1420 on 2011-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on 2011-12-19**:
Done, i can simulate now!

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-13**:
Then, you should change the parameter value of the use_sim_time as true in the launch file.

**Comment by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on 2011-12-12**:
I saw that at the very beginning of the launch file the parameter has been setting as false....

**Comment by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on 2011-12-12**:
I'm doing exactly this: 1- run the roscore 2- run the nodes 3- rosbag play bag.bag --clock but I keep getting the same error and the time printed in the messages as roswarn or rosinfo is not the one in the massages i'm simulating.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to set /use_sim_time to true before processes start.  Otherwise they start operating on wall time.  And then the simulated time is significantly behind wall time, and most code cannot handle backwards jumps in time.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2